# itunes cards purchased in US and used in Africa or Turkey

Tags: apple-id, itunes-store, wallet

i have a friend in Turkey and is asking me to purchase an iTunes card for $200 but if you have an iTunes account can't you put a credit card on it to make purchases like Netflix. They are only over there for a few months for work so does their account not work over there?  If I buy in US how do I get the card to them if they cant receive mail? Do I just purchase here and give them the number on the card? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

That’s how many online services work when selling Apple gift cards. They email the redemption codes and hope that no one else gets the email and redeems them. It’s the first person to claim the code that gets the money.

I would send the code over iMessage since that’s encrypted quite securely.

If you were doing a lot of this, I would read the terms and conditions since this is likely against the literal terms, but if you are helping someone that legitimately has a US App Store account and is simply traveling and not wanting to wait for the physical card to ship, I can’t imagine Apple coming down on you or them once you explained the situation if it somehow was flagged as improper.

Your friends could also enter their AppleID into wallet on their iPhone or iPad and then send you a screen shot that you could take to an Apple store and have the employees scan and then take your payment. That credits the AppleID instantly - no need to send the redemption code.

[image]

I haven’t tried sharing the wallet item, but they might do that as well if you have an iPad or iPhone and could take that into the store for purchase.